Could a Luna-based colony successfully revolt against Earth?
Let’s say that a colony established by humans on Earth’s moon was, for whatever reason, entering a revolutionary war with Earth for its own long-term sovereignty as a planet/nation. Mars has also been colonized; it owes allegiance to Earth but has some sympathies for Luna, as they are in similar situations.
It may be possible for the colony to fight Earth using the methods mentioned in this post, but war isn’t just a physical fight.
Would it be possible for the moon to win this war and become free without the complete destruction or debilitation of one or both combatants? If so, could long-term freedom be achieved, or would this be unrealistic?
Some world context:

In this situation, Luna is self sufficient enough to survive on a basic level (nutrient and air recycling, calorie production, etc) but rely on other bodies (not necessarily Earth - Mars and the asteroid belt are in play) for raw materials to create new projects or complete repairs.
Space travel is significantly faster than we have now. Not instant or light speed, but much faster. It might take a few hours to reach Luna from the Earth’s surface on a good day.
Earth’s governments have been generally united into one planet-wide entity.


The people on Luna at least have one thing going for them: if they can launch a telephone pole on a rocket that can get it going up to 1 km/s, then they can drop orbital strikes on Earth.

I think I'd need to know more about how the people on Luna live.  Do they need resources from Earth or are they self-sufficient?

Ian McDonald explored this concept in his Luna series.  I think the third book is where conflict with Earth took place.

More details on how self-sufficient the inhabitants of Luna are (or aren't) would make this a better, more easily answered question.

This has been explored many times before in fiction, with Heinlein's The Moon Is A Harsh Mistress being probably the most famous.  However, this question is likely to be closed because it violates multiple rules - there is insufficient detail about the situation (colony and Earth), it would require a book-length answer and it is ultimately a story-based question since how things turn out is up to the author.  Note that IRL Earth is not one political entity and there are treaties re the moon, making this very complicated with lots of possibilities.

Too vague.  For instance, if transportation between Earth and Moon is too difficult or takes too long (most Moon inhabitants having been born there) it could probably succeed.

@SailingJudo I appreciate your patience - I’m new to this! I’ve edited by question to include some more details that may be helpful and to specify the inquiry itself.

To answer that, consider first: WHY would Earth have a lunar colony?
It could be for exploration, it could to secure humanity's survival in case of Terran WW3, it could be even a cultural-religious imperative, but the most likely reason is economic: to mine He3 for Terran reactors.
If so, then the Moon can "revolt" just by throwing the few Terran CEOs and handlers out of the airlock, and declaring economic independence. Earth would then pretend to rattle their sabers for a few weeks, send a few angry emails, maybe even send a token "peacekeeping force" to Luna, purely for PR reasons, and then graciously oblige and grant Luna independence.
The cost of ruining Lunar Colony with bombardment or space-infantry assaults, let alone possible retaliation from Luna is great, but the fact that a war with Luna means NO He3 DELIVERY for months on end will make Earth politicians sweat with anxiety.
The cold, hard truth, as cold and hard as interplanetary vacuum, is that Earth needs fuel, and Luna needs resources+colonists, and any kind of war is bad for business for both. Unless the Luna folk are actual Lunatics and decide to be pointlessly murderous, warmongering terrorists, Earth has nothing to gain from fighting them, and everything to gain from making peace.
In fact, in some scenarios, Luna Revolt might be purposely engineered by Earth, as a cost-cutting measure. Consider this: as long as Luna is a Terran colony, Earth has to pay for everything, and provide everything. It makes Earth a welfare state for Lunar Colonists. But if Luna becomes independent, then their relationship becomes purely capitalistic: He3 goes one way, biomatter (food and colonists) the other way. If Luna then faces a food crisis, epidemics, gets hit with a meteor shower, or runs out of air filters? Tough titties, pay more He3 or die, Loonies. Should have thought of that before you rebelled! You wanted to be grown up and independent, don't run crying to Momma Earth when things get tough!

Ultimately I would expect this to be mutually destructive but Earth would win in the long run.
Luna would have little problem wrecking whatever infrastructure on Earth it wanted via kinetic strikes.  However, I imagine Luna would have a much more fragile infrastructure and it would probably take only a few strategic strikes from Earth to completely doom Luna.  Earth would always be able to recover, even if it took centuries.  Luna not so much.
Luna will likely need a diplomatic solution.

It depends also a lot on the technological level of the Moon. There is some chance that the best people (astronauts, top engineers, etc) are going there first, and they might create a very developed society. The infrastructural development is much more work-intensive, they need to build an industrial pressure chamber with radiation protection and self-sustaining ecology, where we can just build a house. But, they would have top guys everywhere. In this sense, I believe, they might have some chance to build also nuclear war surviving infrastructure.

Logic is, a self-sustaining Lunar city under 100m of Moon crust is not so much harder task as a self-sustaining Lunar city under glass sky. Because the main task is the self-sustainability.

I might be slightly confused but a 'revolt' against Earth implies Earth already controls  the lunar colonies. If so it has to be through one of three basic means;

military occupation - boots on the ground.
the threat of attack.
economic/financial coercion.

If the colonies are occupied by a military force the only answer is to fight to remove it. Then negotiate. If the problem is the threat of attack? The moon MUST either have or be able to quickly devise some means of threatening the Earth back (aka the Moon is Harsh Mistress). And if the problem is economic coercion? Unless it involves a resource (skilled personnel?) that can only be obtained from Earth you've already stated the answer i.e fast space transportation and exploitable resources elsewhere in the solar system.
But the key thing is unless Earth is run by a dictatorship or has zero interest in space travel, the rest of the solar system or the resources it contains? Then the  Earth and Moon are too closely bound together both (physically and economically) to prosper in space and fight wars against each other. Even a cold ones. If the Earth has orbital infrastructure and ships and is exploring space? Then orbital mechanics makes it essential that both parties at the least don't interfere with each other.
So barring the two exceptions I mentioned above? The chances are that if the Moon 'revolted' the Earth would simply do it's sums and say 'OK as long as we all agree that.....' Then every one would just get on with business as usual while carefully navigating around Cislunar space.

The Moon is a Harsh Mistress is quite an interesting sci-fi novel about the revolution and independence war of a lunar colony. The book has a strong marxist odor, so read with precaution, but anyways the story is impressive.

Important part of the story, what strongly differs from the "usual" independence wars:

Price of the lunar transfer is still astronomical.
Neither side has experience about interplanetary wars, they improvise.
Moon->Earth transfer is much more easy as vice versa, actually that makes the Moon to finally win the war: they can just throw to the Earth anything. The lunar escape velocity is quite small. While the Earth still has to pay the price of a lunar transfer to get there.

Although the book was written in 1966, as I can remember, it missed the possibility of the nuclear armaments. Very likely, it was because the ICBMs were only lesser known at the time, and the future WW3 was imagined like the WW2 was, extended with the nuclear bombardment from military aircrafts.
Today, things would not be so easy. A Sarmat rocket can go anywhere on the Earth, just like its USA pairs, and contrary the hopes, there is no trustably working defense against it. To get anywhere on the Earth, the Sarmat needs about 9 km/s delta V.
With about 11 km/s, it already could go to the Moon and it would not be a very big cost increase.
In the Moon->Earth direction, already the medium range rockets could deliver nuclear weapons.
On this reason, I believe, having a multiplanar humanity would not help too much against our collective suicide in the form of a total nuclear war.
To get a realistic story, you need some mechanism to prevent it. Then, Moon could use his huge advantage that they can get to us much more easily as vice versa.

The one thing I had never expected to read about Heinlein is him being called a Marxist. He was most definitely not anywhere near the left side of the political spectrum, and TMIAHM is about as Marxist as Atlas Shrugged.

@AlexP Yes, any time if I mention this, the Heinlein fans collect and ask with eyes wide open, what is this. I say to you, what is this. Heinlein was a communist, inside communism he was probably the follower of the late 68's line, and not of the CCCP line of the early Brezhnev era, but communist for sure. It does not prevent me to offer and refer his books, but I also won't neglect it.
